# How to fetch wordpress function in custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress how can we use functions like is_user_logged_in(), we can use this function in any page like header.php , sidebar.php

In wordpress page we are making a form which will be submitted using ajax. Suppose we are gatering form's data on a page 'submitform.php' whose url is www.mysite.com/submitform.php which is totally a custom page.

Now how will I be able to know using is_user_logged_in(); function whether user is logged in or not. because submitform.php is a simple page outside wordpress.

Comment: just include wp-load.php file. eg: `require('./wp-load.php');`

Comment: You shouldn't...Create a custom plugin, or `include` your custom file in *functions.php* and add it to the proper `wp_ajax` hooks

Comment: @Tamil Selvan its not working

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your custom PHP file, use the following to load WordPress core functionality. This assumes your file is in the root of the installation:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```